# FasterCSV default options and their usage

Tags: ruby, csv, rubygems, fastercsv

FasterCSV has a default options hash;

```
DEFAULT_OPTIONS = { :col_sep => ",",
                    :row_sep => :auto,
                    :quote_char => '"',
                    :converters => nil,
                    :unconverted_fields => nil,
                    :headers => false,
                    :return_headers => false,
                    :header_converters => nil,
                    :skip_blanks => false,
                    :force_quotes => false }
```

These options can be overridden by passing a hash to FasterCSV read and write methods. Most of them are self explanatory and easy to use but I couldn't find documentation explaining their usage. Is this information available (I haven't been able to find any credible source on the internet) I have had to resort to just trying them out to see what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FasterCSV has replaced the former CSV module in the standard library and is since then renamed to 'CSV'. Have a look at the [new method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) for the options.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still on ruby 1.8 hence FasterCSV, I should've looked at CSV instead.